# How to set a system property from a python script to use it in Java code?

Tags: java, python, properties, system

I want a String in Java code whose value is set in a python script. Can I set it as a System Property from the script in order to use it with System.getProperty() method. Is there some way to achieve this or using some other approach?

Comment: You may use Jython ans reverse the problem

Comment: Depending on the concrete task of the java application it may also be more appropriate to pass the value as a simple command line argument.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using pyspark you can use the setSystemProperty() method of the SparkContext, e.g.

```
import pyspark
sc=pyspark.SparkContext()
sc.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a Java property on the command line like this:

```
java -D<propertyName1>=<propertyVal1> -D<propertyName2>=<propertyVal2> ...
```

The System.getProperty("propertyName1") will return "propertyVal1".

Example:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar MyJar.jar
```

This will work in a bash script. I've never tried it from Python, but i guess this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) might help you achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jython, you can import java.lang.System class and call the System.setProperty() method to set whatever system properties you want to set:

Code snippets:

```html
from java.lang import System
System.setProperty('app.env', 'DEV')

from yourpackage import YourMainClass
args = ['Your','Args']
YourMainClass.main(args)
```